# ANYSY Journal popup window issue

Tags: python, ironpython, fluent, ansys

I'm trying to automate the simulation workflow in ANSYS Workbench by using the built in journal recorder to record all the inputs and then make copies of the recorded code and run it multiple times. Everything works fine, but sometimes a window pops up in Fluent notifiying that the settings have changed and the user must confirm it before it continues. Sadly this window pops up randomly, so I would need to check for it's presence with some sort of IF sentence, but journal recording uses IronPython with a very strange (for me at least) syntax and I have no idea how to put together the IF sentence that would check the presence of this window.

The piece of code bellow confirms the pop-up window:

setup1.SendCommand(Command='(cx-gui-do cx-activate-item "Settings have changed!*PanelButtons*PushButton1(OK)")')